# select elements by condition using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am having a `ul` with `li` and `<i>` tag as children. The code is as below

```
<li class="accordion put">
  <span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span><span style="padding-left:5px;font-size: 18px;">Topic-Heading</span>
  <ul class="panel2" style="display: none;">
    <li class="testing"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> section 1</li>
    <li class="testing"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> section 2 </li>
    <li class="testing"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> section 3</li>
    <li class="testing"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> section 4 </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I have the below jquery code to toggle the class on click on the `li` as shown below:

```
$(".put.accordion" ).click(function() {
    $(this).children("ul").toggle("slow");
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle");
});
```

The above code is working fine when I click on the `li` tag but since I have mentioned `find('i')` both the `i` tags are changing. I need to toggle only the `i` element having the `class` as `fa-plus-circle` and to ignore the `i` with class `fa-chevron-right`.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a class independent way of selecting the first `<i>`, you can use [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) to reduce the matched results to the first returned `<i>` only.

In your case you could replace this line:

```
$(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle");
```

With this:

```
$(this).find("i").first().toggleClass("fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle");
```

---

A generic example:

```js
$('body').on('click', function() {
    console.log( $(this).find('i').first().text() )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click anywhere to return the contents of the first <code>&lt;i&gt;</code>.</p>

<i class="first">First</i>
<i class="second">Second</i>
<i class="third">Third</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same syntax in [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) as with other jQuery selectors. Just specify the class:

```
$(".put.accordion" ).click(function() {
   $(this).children("ul").toggle("slow");
   $(this).find("i.fa-plus-circle i.fa-minus-circle").toggleClass("fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find  with :

`find("i[class=fa-plus-circle]")`

Detail in : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp. hope to help you